# Is it possible to use signalr or wcf in aws lambda

Tags: c#, wcf, signalr, aws-lambda

I'm currently writing a solution to utilize Amazon Echo to control some smart devices. My intention was Echo -> Lambda Function (C#) -> SignalR Hub (mono on raspberry pi); however, it seems I'm unable to create a SignalR client in an AWS Lambda function. I'm able to add the NuGet packages required, however I cannot reference the Microsoft.ASPNet.SignalR.Client namespace. Am I making a silly mistake, or is this scenario not possible / recommended. If it's the latter, would I be able to communicate from AWS Lambda using wcf?

Thanks in advance for your help.